# How to make a file save prompt in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpexcel

I just started using PHPExcel in my Zend Framework project and now I would like to make a multiple select box with save to a file button next to it like so:

```
SELECT BOX WITH INFO
-------------------   
option1           -
option2           -
.                 -
.                 -
.                 -
-------------------

---------------------------
save to excel file button -
---------------------------
```

How to get this file-save-to-prompt functionality in PHPExcel?

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPExcel doesn't provide any GUI facilities, so it can't generate a select box for you. It is purely a library for reading, writing and manipulating spreadsheet files. If you want interaction with a user front-end, you need to write that yourself.